# Nodejs event loop promise executes before process.tick

Tags: node.js, callback, stack, es6-promise, event-loop

```js
const axiosTest = async () => {

    setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('immediate axios');
    })

    const x = axios.get('https://www.google.com');

    x.then((r) => console.log('fetch'));

    const x2 = new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve('promise axios')
    });

    x2.then(console.log)

    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('tick axios')
    });

    console.log('stack axios');
}

const normalTest = async () => {

    setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('immediate');
    })

    const x = new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve('promise')
    });

    x.then(console.log)

    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('tick')
    });

    console.log('stack');
}
```

`normalTest().then(axiosTest);`

Execution order:

```
stack
tick
promise
stack axios
promise axios
tick axios
immediate
immediate axios
fetch
```

`normalTest()`

Execution order:

```
stack
tick
promise
immediate
```

`axiosTest()`

Execution order:

```
stack axios
tick axios     
promise axios  
immediate axios
fetch
```

When I just run the axiosTest function, tick executes before promise resolve but when I run it after normalTest function promise resolves first. Why is that?

I expected to promise.tick to execute before any promise resolve in the same scope but it did not.

Answer (score 1):

The `process.nextTick` callback is scheduled at the end of the current "phase". The [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#event-loop-explained) define *phase* as the processing of one FIFO queue during the event loop:

> When Node.js starts, it initializes the event loop, processes the provided input script (or drops into the REPL, which is not covered in this document) which may make async API calls, schedule timers, or call process.nextTick(), then begins processing the event loop.
>
> The following diagram shows a simplified overview of the event loop's order of operations.
>
> ```
>    ┌───────────────────────────┐
> ┌─>│           timers          │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
> │  │     pending callbacks     │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
> │  │       idle, prepare       │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
> │  │           poll            │<─────┤  connections, │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      └───────────────┘
> │  │           check           │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
> └──┤      close callbacks      │
>    └───────────────────────────┘
> ```
>
> Each box will be referred to as a "phase" of the event loop.

We can reproduce the change of order with this simplified script:

```
const test = async () => {
    console.log('------------test-------------');
    process.nextTick(() => console.log('tick'));
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise resolved'))
}

test().then(test)
```

The output is:

```
------------test-------------
tick
promise resolved
------------test-------------
promise resolved
tick
```

The difference is that `test` is executed from different phases which implies different orders. Here is a step by step analysis that should clarify this:

When the main script has finished its synchronous part (i.e. `test` has been executed once), we have this state:

1. `() => console.log('tick')` is waiting to execute after the current *phase*
2. `() => console.log('promise resolved')` is waiting in the promise job queue
3. `test` is waiting in the promise job queue (second entry)

When the synchronous part ends, the engine prepares to enter the event loop and tackle the next phase. However, before transitioning to a next phase, the tick callbacks are executed. So this explains "tick" comes first.

At some point in the event loop we get to the promise job phase (not specifically indicated in above simplified diagram): this is where first 'promise resolved' is output and then `test` is executed (its second execution).

Again `test` will do something similar:

1. `() => console.log('tick')` is waiting to execute after the current *phase*
2. `() => console.log('promise resolved')` is waiting in the promise job queue

But now we should realise we are still in the promise job phase, and in that phase it is found that the promise job queue is still not empty (we just added a new job there), and so there is no transition to a next phase, and by consequence it is not yet the time to make a "tick".

So this time, 'promise resolved' is output first, and then this *phase* ends as there  are no more promise jobs in the promise job queue: now is the time to make a tick, and 'tick' is output.

#### Remark

This concept of a *tick* and that `nextTick` callbacks execute after the current *phase* is not part of the ECMA Script language specification.

Personally I would stay away from ever calling `nextTick`.